# R What to do when both DOM and SAX parsers fail?

Tags: xml, r, sax

I have a very large xml file of around 45 GB that I am trying to parse and create a data frame out of. The xml has a fairly simple structure to it as shown below. I want to read the attributes under the tag `<event>` when the type is either *entered link* or *left link*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<events version="1.0">
    <event time="10800.0" type="actend" person="9982471" link="21225" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10800.0" type="departure" person="9982471" link="21225" legMode="car"  />
    <event time="10800.0" type="PersonEntersVehicle" person="9982471" vehicle="9982471"  />
    <event time="10800.0" type="actend" person="9656271" link="21066" actType="home"  />
    <event time="10833.0" type="entered link" person="4250461" link="24329" vehicle="4250461"  />
    <event time="10835.0" type="left link" person="1662941" link="29242" vehicle="1662941"  />
    <event time="10835.0" type="entered link" person="1662941" link="29239" vehicle="1662941"  />
    <event time="10836.0" type="left link" person="7651702" link="7359" vehicle="7651702"  />
    <event time="10836.0" type="entered link" person="7651702" link="7407" vehicle="7651702"  />
    <event time="10840.0" type="left link" person="8909152" link="5664" vehicle="8909152"  />
</events>
```

I have tried the DOM based `xmlparse()` function but it is not helpful due to memory issues. Then, I tried a SAX based code (shown below) but it is taking too long. For example, to read a 1% sample and create a dataframe from it, it took me about 5 hours. So, to do the same with the full data it would take me about 20 days (assuming it could be scaled linearly). Can you please help me solve this issue? Here are the links to a [very small sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4u0mlpdrctyvhk9/xml.xml?dl=0), [1% sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dnc2brzz7ud1zmg/percent1.gz?dl=0), [5% sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/210g0wf8vasiy1y/percent5.gz?dl=0), and the [full data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/boncz3d0nhey7y5/percent100.gz?dl=0).

Here is the SAX code I used.

```
library(XML)

branchFunction <- function() {
  store <- new.env() 
  new_counter <- (function() {
    i <- 0
    function() { 
      i <<- i + 1
      i
    }
  })()
  func <- function(x, ...) {
    ns <- getNodeSet(x,path = "//event[@type='left link' or @type='entered link']")
    value <- lapply(ns, xmlAttrs)
    store[[toString(new_counter())]] <- value
  }
  getStore <- function() { as.list( store ) }
  list(event = func, getStore=getStore)
}

myfunctions <- branchFunction()

xmlEventParse(file = "percent1.gz", handlers = NULL, branches = myfunctions)
l <- myfunctions$getStore()
l <- unlist(l, recursive = FALSE)
df <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(l), nrow=length(l), byrow=T),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
colnames(df) <- c("time", "type", "person", "link", "carid")
```

The output must look like this

```
> head(df)
     time         type  person  link   carid
1 10934.0 entered link 9656271 16260 9656271
2 10935.0    left link 8909152  6014 8909152
3 10935.0 entered link 8909152  6034 8909152
4 10936.0    left link 1504062 25541 1504062
5 10936.0 entered link 1504062 25384 1504062
6 10936.0    left link 3055801 31464 3055801
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong in your SAX approach, probably reprocessing the entire file for each XPath expression.

Comment: It could be. But, I don't know if and what is the issue with my code.

Comment: In XPath, the double forward slash, `//` searches anywhere in the xml document and is often considered an expensive method as each command scans all underlying descendants in tree structure.

Comment: @Parfait I did benchmark the code with `//` and `/` and both seemed to give the same run time on a small sample. Although, your point is well taken. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Saxon, the following XSLT 3.0 stylesheet processed your percent1 sample (413Mb) in 14.5 seconds:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:stream href="percent1.xml">
      <xsl:for-each select="/events/event[@type=('entered link', 'left link')]">
        {position()} {@time} {@person} {@link} {@person}
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:stream>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Memory usage was 13Mb (which isn't going to increase as the file size increases). Extrapolated time for the full dataset about 25 minutes.

Comment: @MichaelKay. Thanks for the solution. However, when I run this using `java -cp "C:\Users\u\Dropbox\saxon9.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:percent100.xml -xsl:readplans.xsl -o:output.txt` it gives me the error `Error at xsl:stream on line 8 column 39 of readplans.xsl:
  XTSE0010: Unknown XSLT element: stream` . The only change I did to your style sheet is     `<xsl:stream href="percent100.xml">`

Comment: This is an XSLT 3.0 stylesheet using streaming, so you'll need Saxon-EE to run it. You can get a free 30day evaluation license.

Comment: Ok. I sent a request. Just curious about this line `<xsl:stream href="percent100.xml">`. Isn't this redundant given that I am providing the source file in the above command line syntax?

Comment: You shouldn't provide the source file in the command, or Saxon will build the source document in memory. It's best to start the transformation at a named template using the -it option, with no source document.

Comment: Is there any issue with my [stylesheet](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ya61ns0473ziuzv/readplans.xsl?dl=0) ? Here is the command line syntax I am using `java -cp "C:\Users\u\Dropbox\saxon9ee.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:readplans.xsl -o:output.txt` and I am getting the error `Error at xsl:template on line 7 column 38 of readplans.xsl:
  XTSE0080: Namespace prefix xsl refers to a reserved namespace
Errors were reported during stylesheet compilation` Sorry for coming back again and again. I tried multiple variations using -it without any success. I also put the license in the same folder.

Comment: Although I don't understand why, I changed the tag from `<xsl:template name="xsl:readplans">` to  `<xsl:template name="xsl:initial-template">` and used the command line syntax `java -cp "C:\Users\u\Dropbox\saxon9ee.jar" net.sf.saxon.Transform -it -xsl:initial-template.xsl -t -o:output.txt`. It's totally working fine now. The run did not yet finish, but I think there should not be any problem.

Answer (score 0):

To extend @MichaelKay's answer, consider an XSLT solution. As information, XSLT is special-purpose declarative programming language used specifically to transform XML files to various formats including other XML, HTML, even text (txt, csv, etc.) for end use needs such as R data frames.

Most general purpose languages including C#, Java, Perl, Python, PHP, VB come equipped with XSLT 1.0 libraries -some like Java with XSLT 2.0 and 3.0 libraries such as [Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml) and [Xalan](https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/). Plus, command line interpreters like PowerShell and Bash can run XSLT. R even has the limited [Sxslt](https://github.com/omegahat/Sxslt) library using the libxslt gnome module  but is restricted to Linux machines.

R can call other scripts and/or executables as a child process using `system()` as shown below. For your large XML file, consider transforming into csv file(s) for R to import (removing any parsing need):

**XSLT** *(save externally usually as .xsl or .xslt)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"  method="text"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <!-- Identity Transform -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" priority="1">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Comma-separated values -->
  <xsl:template match="event[@type=('entered link','left link')]" priority="2">    
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@time, ',',
                                 @type, ',',
                                 @person, ',',
                                 @link, ',',
                                 @vehicle)"/><xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**CSV** Output *(using above sample)*

```
#10833  entered link    4250461 24329 4250461
#10835  left link       1662941 29242 1662941
#10835  entered link    1662941 29239 1662941
#10836  left link       7651702 7359  7651702
#10836  entered link    7651702 7407  7651702
#10840  left link       8909152 5664  8909152
```

**R** Script

```
# COMMAND LINE CALL(S)
# PYTHON SCRIPT (USING LXML MODULE)
system('python dir/XSLT_Transform_Script.py')  
# SAXON HE (JAVA PLATFORM)
system('java -jar dir/saxonhe.jar -s:Input.xml -xsl:XSLTscript.xsl -o:Output.csv')  
# BASH UNIX XSLTPROC
system('xsltproc XSLTscript.xsl Input.xml -o Output.csv')  
# POWERSHELL WINDOWS SCRIPT W/ ARGS
system('Powershell.exe -File XSLTransform_Script.ps1 Input.xml, XSLTScript.xsl, Output.csv')

# DATA FRAME IMPORT
df <- read.csv("Output.csv", header=FALSE)
colnames(df) <-  c("time", "type", "person", "link", "carid")
```